# Windows 10 TileText property behaving super weird

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

So I've been working on a Win10 Universal App and wanted to create some live tiles for it. I'm using the **NotificationExtensions** library for achieving this. However, I ran into a super weird behavior which doesn't make any sort of sense to me. Basically, I'm trying to assign some string to the Text property of a TileText and it wouldn't work in certain conditions. Let me exemplify a bit:

```
public sealed class ConnectionRequestDetailsTile : TileLayoutBase
{
     private readonly ResourceLoader m_resLoader;

     public ConnectionRequestDetailsTile(int connectionRequestCount, ResourceLoader resLoader)
     {
        if (resLoader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resLoader));
        }
        m_resLoader = resLoader;

        //TileHeader.Text = m_resLoader.GetString("Connections");
        //TileStaticText.Text = m_resLoader.GetString("Requests");
        //TileData.Text = connectionRequestCount.ToString();

        TileHeader.Text = "Connections";
        TileStaticText.Text = "Requests";
        TileData.Text = connectionRequestCount.ToString();
     }

     public override async Task<TileNotification> UpdateTileAsync()
     {
        ...
     }
    .....
   }
}

public abstract class TileLayoutBase
{
    public virtual TileText TileHeader => new TileText
    {
        Style = TileTextStyle.Caption,
        Align = TileTextAlign.Left,
        MaxLines = 1
    };

    public virtual TileText TileStaticText => new TileText
    {
        Style = TileTextStyle.CaptionSubtle,
        Align = TileTextAlign.Center,
        MaxLines = 1
    };

    public virtual TileText TileData => new TileText
    {
        Style = TileTextStyle.Body,
        Align = TileTextAlign.Center,
        MaxLines = 1
    };

    public virtual TileImage TileIcon => new TileImage
    {
        Align = TileImageAlign.Left,
        RemoveMargin = true,
        Source = new TileImageSource("some_image_source")
    };

    protected virtual TileBinding CreateSmallTileBinding()
    {
        TileGroup tileGroup = new TileGroup();
        TileSubgroup tileSubGroup = new TileSubgroup { TextStacking = TileTextStacking.Center };
        ... // code to create a medium sized binding
    }

    protected virtual TileBinding CreateLargeTileBinding()
    {
        TileGroup tileGroup = new TileGroup();
        TileSubgroup tileSubGroup = new TileSubgroup { TextStacking = TileTextStacking.Center };
        ... // code to create a large tile binding
    }

    public abstract Task<TileNotification> UpdateTileAsync();
 }
```

The problem here is the ***Text property doesn't do any assignment***. Whenever I step over the line where I want to set the text in my subclass, **the Text stays null**. I initially thought this must be a problem with their implementation of the setter in the NotificationExtensions library, so I grabbed it and decompiled it. To my surprise, all seems normal:

```
public sealed class TileText : ITileSubgroupChild, ITileAdaptiveChild
{
    private int _maxLines = int.MaxValue;
    private int _minLines = 1;

    public string Text { get; set; }

   ...
 }
```

If I assign the text in the base class (where I set all the other common properties, everything works fine and dandy). Also, in the immediate window, everything seems to work just fine as well. I suspect it's got something to do with the inheritance, but I have no idea what it could be. Here's a link to MSDN with more information about the library:
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/08/20/introducing-notificationsextensions-for-windows-10.aspx](http://NotificationExtensions%20info)

Some help would be well appreciated. It's annoying to have to work around such issues with uglier, more unnatural code. Thanks!